# React Router Hash Link: Anchor tag does not scroll to expected position

Tags: javascript, reactjs, anchor, react-router-dom

I use `react-router-dom` in my project and facing difficulties with navigating to the proper position on the FAQ page (https://search-guard.com/faq). I tried anything from just using `a` tags, `react-router-hash-link`, I even tried to generate random IDs for the anchors with `uuid` (which somehow was the worst outcome) but the result is always the same: some links work perfectly fine (mostly the first few links and the last ones) but some are just landing 'too low'.

I even tried to use `ul` and `li` instead of just `div` code structure but again: the result is always the same and I have no clue why. Does the problem sound familiar to anyone? I thought that `react-router-hash-link` was developed to solve it but unfortunately it didn't.

The solution for now is adding some padding for those links where it doesn't reach the expected position. Cherry on top: it's not working at all on mobile.